# Function is not returning true value

Tags: laravel

I have a Model that takes care of followers:

```
    Schema::create('follows', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->integer('user_id');
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('follower_id');
        $table->dateTime('followed_date')->nullable();
        $table->dateTime('unfollowed_date')->nullable();
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->unique(['user_id', 'follower_id']);
    });
```

The issue is I have this piece of code in the User.php model that is not returning true when I follow the user:

```
public function following()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Follow::class);
}

public function isFollowing($profileUser)
{
    return $this->following()->where(['user_id' => $profileUser, 'follower_id' => auth()->id()])->exists();
}
```

Here is the code that I have in the view:

```
@if(auth()->user()->isFollowing($profileUser->id) == FALSE)
<li>
    <form action="/follow/{{ $profileUser->name }}" method="POST">
        {{ csrf_field() }}
        <input type="hidden" name="user_id" value="{{ $profileUser->id }}">
        <input type="hidden" name="follower_id" value="{{ auth()->user()->id }}">
        <button type="submit">Follow</button>
    </form>
</li>
@else
<li>
    <form action="/follow/{{ $profileUser->name }}" method="POST">
        {{ csrf_field() }}
        <input type="hidden" name="user_id" value="{{ $profileUser->id }}">
        <input type="hidden" name="follower_id" value="{{ auth()->user()->id }}">
        <button type="submit">Unfollow</button>
    </form>
</li>
@endif
```

Does anyone know why my code is not working? Thanks in advance!

Comment: you probably have the keys backwards that you are looking for ... and you don't need to add a where condition for the User you are calling that method for as its part of the relationship already ... try `where('follower_id', $profileUser)` instead .... kinda looks like you have a pivot table the way you are trying to do this ... i would assume you are not creating 2 records for every follower followee relationship

Comment: Would creating 2 records for every follower followee be good? Serious question. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the issue was I didn't even know the structure of my Model,

I confused the user_id column with the $request->follower_id,

I'm going to make it following_id to make it more clear what the relationship is...

A user will be "following" another user... simple!